# Nvidia Tesla PH402 dual P100 card shows on lspci but not on nvidia-smi

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, nvidia

I installed my Dual P100 64G card and I can't get nvidia-smi or deviceQuery to recognize it.

I tried with the default ubuntu drivers and with drivers from nvidia website installed manually (after a cleanup of the default ones) without success. I followed [this procedure](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&target_distro=Ubuntu&target_version=2004&target_type=deblocal) to install the CUDA toolkit and compile utilities including deviceQuery but I always get `No devices were found`.

Here is some output :

```
$ lspci -nn | grep 3D
03:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:15fa] (rev a1)
04:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:15fa] (rev a1)

$ nvidia-smi 
No devices were found

$ cat /proc/driver/nvidia/version 
NVRM version: NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  460.32.03  Sun Dec 27 19:00:34 UTC 2020
GCC version:  gcc version 9.3.0 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 

$ ./deviceQuery Starting...

 CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)

cudaGetDeviceCount returned 100
-> no CUDA-capable device is detected
Result = FAIL
```

The only place where I seem to find a link between the driver and the card is in `/sys/bus/pci/drivers/nvidia` where I see folders for my Tesla chips PCI ids `0000:03:00.0` and `0000:04:00.0`

How can I get them to work as intended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was a hardware one, my old board did not support memory addressing large enough for the 64G the card had. It requires enabling "Above 4G Decoding" in the Bios and disabling CSM support and my old board does not support above 4G Decoding.

On an Asus TUF x570 Plus though with the proper Bios settings it worked! I can use the cards, I see them in nvidia-smi and all.

See more details on the Nvidia forums :

https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/ph402-dual-p100-64g-rminitadapter-failed-memory-mapping-issue/173877